# Changing activity background by path

Tags: android, android-activity, background-image

I try to change the background of my Activity ( onCreate ) randomly. It stucks in the the last step ... show it. Maybe someone has an idea for me.

I created an array within a xml file which contains 5+ drawable's - it looks like this ..

```
<array name="backgrounds">
   <item>@drawable/bg1_320x480</item>
   <item>@drawable/bg2_320x480</item>
   <item>@drawable/bg3_320x480</item>
   <item>@drawable/bg4_320x480</item>
   <item>@drawable/bg5_320x480</item>
   <item>@drawable/bg6_320x480</item>
</array>
```

Within my main activity, I get one random element out of the array ...

```
String[] mTempArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.backgrounds);
    int iMin = 0;
    int iMax = 5;
    int randomIndex = iMin + (int) (Math.random() * iMax);
    String resPath = mTempArray[randomIndex];
```

resPath return me (e.g.) **res/drawable-hdpi/bg4_320x480.png**. From this point on, I found a lot of solutions, but nothing brings me to succes.

What is the last point to set / change / overwrite the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resource ID is just an integer--there's no need to deal with strings. You can use something like this
`int[] imageIds = new int[] { R.drawable.bg1, R.drawable.bg2, ... };`
, pick a random element, and set it as your background. Not sure if you can encode the array of resource IDs in xml.